# A customer without a tax rule is possible?

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-rule

I have a Tax Zones and Rates for my store (21% per each country) but I have some customers that I need to configure to avoid paying this tax. Is it possible to configure a user to not be assigned this rule?

Comment: How about a customer group to which tax does not apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Admin > Stores > Tax Rules > Edit Tax Rule
2. Create new tax class(lets call it No Tax) Additional Settings > Add New Tax Class
3. Go to Admin > Customer > Customer Groups > Edit or Add New
4. Select No Tax as Customer Group Tax Class
5. Put customer in above customer group. Admin > Customers > Edit > Account Information > Group

[image: Tax Rule]
[image: Customer Group]
[image: Customer Account]

Comment: One question, this solution is very good but I lose the special prices for the group that I had assigned to that user. Is it possible to have a user with two groups assigned?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can add a new "tier price" (What I suspect you are calling special prices, special price applies to all customer groups by default) for the new group. Or you might consider a catalog rule/cart rule.